# Use ScrollWidth for inline Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I have a problem with getting the exact width of the content in a div, which(the content) is sometimes smaller, but also sometimes bigger than the viewport(overflow is hidden). This questions is not about the padding/margin/border problems with the JS-methods.

**clientWidth** and **offsetWidth** will only return the viewable width of the content, in my case the viewport width, since the div is a block level element

**scrollWidth** will give me the width of the content, if the div extends the viewport, but if the div is smaller it will give me the viewport width. The reason is that it always returns the bigger number of the content width and the element width.

---

I am looking for a method which always returns the content width! Also I can´t just set the div to be inline and use scrollWidth() because that will always return 0(doesn´t work with inline).

So basically scrollWidth works for me as long as the content is bigger than the viewport. Do you have any suggestions? If the situation is still unclear I will ad a graphic.

---

**EDIT**

Basically I was just asking how I can use ScrollWidth for inline-Elements, but didn´t understand it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your css rule forces an element to expand its width, `scrollWidth` will return the full width. I think the solution is to make sure your elements aren't stretched by css.

Take this example. The first `div` has `display: inline-block` and will not expand its size. The second `div` has the default `display: block` and will span the width of its relatively positioned parent.

Click on "Expand Snippet/Full page" and resize your window to see the results.

```js
var to = null;
var log = function() {
  console.log("Width 1: ", document.querySelector(".div1").scrollWidth); 
  
  console.log("Width 2: ", document.querySelector(".div2").scrollWidth);  
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  clearTimeout(to);
  
  to = setTimeout(log, 500);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.div2 {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis diam nec arcu consequat rhoncus.
</div>

<div class="div2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis diam nec arcu consequat rhoncus.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, using inline-block works perfectly for me and is basically exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jquery methods

**.height()** Height of box (no margin, border, padding)

**.width()** Width of box (no margin, border, padding)

**.innerHeight()** Height of box plus padding

**.innerWidth()** Width of box plus padding

**.outerHeight()** Height of box plus padding and border

**.outerWidth()** Width of box plus padding and border

**.outerHeight()** (true) Height of box plus padding, border, and margin

**.outerWidth()** (true) Width of box plus padding, border, and margin

Answer (score -1):

If I get your question right, below function will look at **scrollWidth**, if it is greater than clientWidth which means it is overflow otherwise it is fully visible or smaller. Can you give a shot and let me know? I hope it helps.

```
function getAbsoluteWidth(elementIdentifier) {
var $elem=document.getElementById(elementIdentifier);

if($elem.scrollWidth>$elem.clientWidth){
    return $elem.scrollWidth;
}

return $elem.clientWidth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I now realized that clientWidth will always return me the width of the wrapping div and therefore the viewport width, because it is a block level element. I will try to fix that by using inline-block now but then I won`t need your function anymore I think. Thanks a lot for your efforts!